# Malloc a map from a text file for a Hunt The Wumpus game

Tags: c, malloc

I'm working on a game of Hunt The Wumpus. So far, I have a Struct Map which will handle the map for my game and I am given a text file containing information about the map. The text file is as below:

```
5 2
0 1
3 2
2 3
1 4
0 0
```

The first line has two numbers: ROOMS (The number of rooms in the map) & EXITS (The number of exits per room)

**Example:** looking at the first line above the map would have 5 rooms with 2 exits each.

The next line after that gives the connection information for the numbered 0 to ROOMS-1, listing EXITS number of rooms for outgoing connections.

**Example:** looking at the next line, we'd call this room 0 & room 0 connects to itself and room 1 and so on.

So far I have a seperate program to handle loading in the map and other things but am having difficulty dynamically allocating the map and it's connections.

```
/* Struct to hold a cave map. */
struct Map
{
    /* How many rooms in the map/ */
    int rooms;
    /* Number of exits from each room */
    int exitsPerRoom;
    /* Connection info array*/
    int** connections;
}

struct Map* loadMap(FILE* in)
{
    //malloc the map then malloc the connections
}
```

loadmap is where I would like to allocate the map and connections but I am unsure how to go about this. Could someone provide an explanation of how I would do this?

Thanks

Comment: Make a concept and the data structure you want to use before starting to code. Just in case you think you did: Your question shows you are wrong.

Comment: Would this work to dynamically allocate?
    struct Map map = malloc(sizeof(struct Map));
    connections = malloc(sizeof(int)*(rooms*exitsPerRoom));

Comment: Sorry, this is no consulting site. If you really have no idea, this might be too enhanced for your current skill-level. You should do more research and learn further, e.g. with simpler games.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help!

Comment: Ignore the file part, and write functions to build the data-structures. `create_room()` `connect_rooms(room,room)` Since they're just identified with numbers, the top-level structure should just be an array `room map[num_rooms];` ... then do those things based on the file instructions.